# Find monotonically increasing function $f$ on $[ 1,+\infty )$ such that $ x ( f ( x^{2} ) + 1 ) = f ( x ) ( x^{2}+1 ) $?

Tags: functions

Find all monotonically increasing functions $f$ on $\left[1,+\infty\right)$ such that

$$x\left( f \left( x^{2} \right) + 1 \right) = f \left( x \right) \left( x^{2}+1 \right) $$

Does there only exist the unique solution $f(x)=x$?

At first time, I think that $f$ is monotonically increasing is necessary and meaningful here.

Thanks for the comments, there are some strange solutions beyond my thought.

And now it seems the property of monotonically increasing is not important, maybe it is because there exists a closed and beautiful form of the solutions.

Comment: You're not new here, you must be familiar with the policy and guidelines... what have *you* tried?

Comment: No, I mean "what have you tried to solve your question?"

Comment: Thanks, I will try@ClementC.

Comment: Not sure if this will help: every monotonically increasing function is almost everywhere differentiable.

Comment: If this helps the only linear function that satisfies the equality is $f(x)=x$

Comment: @ClementC. Appears taken care of.

Comment: Certainly $f(x)$ must be odd.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  That makes no sense.  The function $f$ is defined only on $[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: @Batominovski Whoops! Completely missed that! If it were $f:\Bbb R\mapsto\Bbb R$, then it would have to be odd.

Comment: **Remark:** The only Laurent polynomials $F(X)\in\mathbb{R}\left[X,\frac{1}{X}\right]$ such that $$F(X)\,\left(X^2+1\right)=X\,\big(F\left(X^2\right)+1\big)$$ are of the form $$F_t(X):=t\,X+\frac{1-t}{X}\,,$$ where $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  In particular, if $t\geq \frac{1}{2}$, then the function $f:[+1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=F_t(x)$ for all $x\geq 1$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks, say, this problem may be more complicated than I thought...

Comment: There are strange solutions like 
$$f(x) = x + \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(A + B\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{\log 2}\log\log x\right)\right)
$$
to the functional equation. If $A > -\frac12$ and 
$\displaystyle\;|B| < \frac{1+2A}{2\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{2\pi}{\log 2}\right)^2}}\;$,
$f(x)$ will be increasing too.

Comment: @achillehui, I am kind of interested in how you came up with this example!

Comment: @achillehui what on Earth or Hell did you have to summon to get access to that?

Comment: Perhaps the idea is that, ignoring the monotonicity, any solution is of the form $$f(x) = x + \left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)\varphi(x) $$ for some $\varphi : [1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(x^2) = \varphi(x)$, or equivalently, $x \mapsto \varphi(\exp(2^x))$ has period $1$. Now all we have to do is some engineering on $\varphi$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yup, you beat me in writing that up as a comment ;-p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly, $f(1)=1$. Now, the functional equation is equivalent to
$$f(x^2)=\left(x+\frac1x\right)f(x)-1$$
This the same as
$$f(x^2)-x^2=\left(x+\frac1x\right)(f(x)-x)$$
Or, if we define $g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)-x}{x-1/x}$ for $x>1$, we get
$$g(x^2)=g(x)\tag1$$
Now the functions $g$ that satisfy $(1)$ are functions of form $g(x)=h(\ln(\ln x))$ where 
$ h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary periodic function having $\ln(2)$ as period.

So, the general solution of the proposed functional equation is
$$f(x)=x+\left(x-\frac1x\right)h(\ln(\ln x))$$
Where $ h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary periodic function having $\ln(2)$ as period.
Now, the monitonicity condition adds some conditions on our choices for $h$.